# Instantiating child (concrete) classes of a generic abstract class whose constructor needs other parametric class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, instantiation

A library I'm trying to use has a generic abstract class with two children classes that implement the base. I want to write a class that will automatically create an instance of one of the children based on parametric type of constructor's argument.

- The base class does not have a default constructor
- The base class's constructor requires instances of other classes that are generic too

#### Snippets

```
public abstract class JsonRequest<T> {
    public JsonRequest(String body, Listener<T> listener) {}
}
public class JsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {
    public JsonArrayRequest(JSONArray body, Listener<JSONArray>) {}
}
public class JsonObjectRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {
    public JsonObjectRequest(JSONObject body, Listener<JSONObject>) {}
}
```

Now I want to wrap the two concrete children so that the wrapper/factory would automatically decide which one to call/instantiate based on class of parametric type, something like this (and I get all sort of compiler errors)

```
public class RequestFactory<T> {
    private Listener<T> mListener;

    public RequestFactory(T body, Listener<T> lis) {
        mListener = lis;
        if (body instanceof JSONArray) {
            // Call JsonArrayRequest constructor
            JsonArrayRequest(body, mListener);
        }
        else if (body instanceof JSONObject) {
            // Call JsonObjectRequest constructor
            JsonObjectRequest(body, mListener);
        }
    }
}
```

- How can I do this? (preferably without casting)
- Is there a better way wrapping `JsonArrayRequest` and `JsonObjectRequest` so that their constructors get automatically called based on type of `body` argument passed?
- Is this possible in Java?

(I'm actually trying to use [Android's Volley library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley))

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Abstract Factory Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

```
public interface RequestFactory<T> {
    public JsonRequest<T> create(T body, Listener<T> listener);
}

public class ArrayRequestFactory implements RequestFactory<JSONArray> {
    @Override
    public JsonArrayRequest create(JSONArray body, Listener<JSONArray> listener) {
        return new JsonArrayRequest(body, listener);
    }
}

public class ObjectRequestFactory implements RequestFactory<JSONObject> {
    @Override
    public JsonObjectRequest create(JSONObject body, Listener<JSONObject> listener) {
        return new JsonObjectRequest(body, listener);
    }
}
```

The constructor is selected through dynamic dispatch in stead of `if` conditions.

Comment: so I would be able to do something like `new RequestFactory<JSONArray>.create()` ?

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example of how to use this?